# #import sentestingkit sentestingkit.h file not found in phonegap on xcode4.3

Tags: iphone, ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am very new to iPhone development and phonegap. I installed phonegap for developing iPhone app using phonegap. Now I installed embedding Cordova Webview following by

```
   "docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding Cordova WebView on iOS"
```

this above link. But now I got

```
"#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>" And #import "<PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>"
![enter image description here][1]
these above error in xcode4.3.
```

Could you please help me to solve these above error? Thanks in advance. 
   ![enter image description here][2]I have attach the error page for your reference.

Comment: can't see the attached image.

Comment: Sir,I Was post the image.But they not accepted.Because I want to post the image means i should have  more than 10 reputation.then only they allow me to post the images.